# Magento 2 - Need to fetch all available Order statuses using REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

There is REST API endpoint for specific order statuses

```
GET    /V1/orders/:id/statuses
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html

But I am looking for approach to fetch all available order statuses using REST API because I am working on external system in which I need to fetch the required magento data.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated

Comment: Are you want just available order status list? Or Particular order status?

Comment: All available order statuses list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created module for that, You can follow this steps for that :

**Step 1 :** Create **registration.php** file at **app/code/RH/OrderStatus**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'RH_OrderStatus',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2 :** Create **module.xml** file at **app/code/RH/OrderStatus/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="RH_OrderStatus" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**Step 3 :** Create **webapi.xml** file at **app/code/RH/OrderStatus/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/getorderstatus" method="GET">
        <service class="RH\OrderStatus\Api\Getorderstatus" method="getorderstatusarray"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="admin"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**Step 4 :** Create **di.xml** file at **app/code/RH/OrderStatus/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="RH\OrderStatus\Api\Getorderstatus" type="RH\OrderStatus\Model\GetorderstatusModel" />
</config>
```

**Step 5 :** Create **Getorderstatus.php** file at **app/code/RH/OrderStatus/Api**

```
<?php
namespace RH\OrderStatus\Api;
interface Getorderstatus {
    /**
     * @api
     * @return array
     */
    public function getorderstatusarray();
}
```

**Step 6 :** Create **GetorderstatusModel.php** file at **app/code/RH/OrderStatus/Model**

```
<?php
namespace RH\OrderStatus\Model;

use RH\OrderStatus\Api\Getorderstatus;

class GetorderstatusModel implements Getorderstatus {

    protected $statusCollectionFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory $statusCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->statusCollectionFactory = $statusCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getorderstatusarray() {
        $options = $this->statusCollectionFactory->create()->toOptionArray();
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Now, Go to Admin -> System -> Integrations and Get **Access Token** value and set authorization value into postman application.

Then, execute `{base_url}/rest/V1/getorderstatus` this URL in postman.

You will get all order status.

[image]
Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: I was looking for rest api endpoints for all available order statuses but there is none. So I decided to made my own custom rest api for all order statuses. I just finished it successfully and just going to share it in answer but you share it before. I did almost the same but you deserve credit. Anyways great work, keep coding :) thanks :) +1 for appreciation.

Comment: My pleasure :) Happy coding !!